# Base SQL Server com colunas criptografadas

Tags: sql-server, criptografia, backup

Tenho uma base SQL na qual criptografei algumas colunas seguindo os passos da seguinte explicação:
https://www.devmedia.com.br/criptografia-de-dados-no-sql-server/37027

Basicamente criei a master key, chve simétrica e certificado. Pelo o que entendi essas informações todas estão atreladas a base de dados e não ao servidor.
Minha dúvida é, imagine que alguém roube um backup dessa minha base e suba em outro servidor SQL, essa pessoa conseguiria ler os dados da base? O certificado, chave simétrica e masterkey funcionariam nesse outro servidor?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta